# How to insert data into sql table from a text field in java

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a program that allows users to insert data into a table.
Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class DbMethods {

    static String query="";
    static Statement statement = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    //  throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
            // Load the JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded");

            // Establish a connection
           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection
              ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook","root","");
            System.out.println("Database connected");

            // Create a statement
            statement = (Statement)connection.createStatement();


        }

    public static void insert() throws SQLException{
        if(!DbInterface.ID.getText().equals("")){

             statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO personnel(ID, LastName, FirstName, mi, Address, City, State, Telephone)" + "VALUES('" + DbInterface.ID.getText() + "','" + DbInterface.lastName.getText() + "','" + DbInterface.firstName.getText() + "','" + DbInterface.mi.getText() + "','" + DbInterface.address.getText() + "','" + DbInterface.city.getText() + "','" + DbInterface.state.getText() + "','" + DbInterface.tel.getText() + "')");

        }
        else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DbInterface.contentPane, "The ID cannot be null!", "Invalid info", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }

    }
```

I also have created another class to keep the textfields in and get the input from the user.I have only added one actionlistener just for the insert button for now.Here is the class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class DbInterface extends JFrame {

    //text_fields
    static JPanel contentPane;
    static JTextField ID;
    static JTextField lastName;
    static JTextField firstName;
    static JTextField mi;
    static JTextField address;
    static JTextField city;
    static JTextField state;
    static JTextField tel;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DbInterface frame = new DbInterface();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DbInterface() {
        setTitle("Personnel Table");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 656, 422);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblPersonel = new JLabel("Personnel Information");
        lblPersonel.setBounds(12, 0, 126, 16);
        panel.add(lblPersonel);

        JLabel lblId = new JLabel("ID");
        lblId.setBounds(12, 29, 56, 16);
        panel.add(lblId);

        ID = new JTextField();
        ID.setBounds(80, 26, 204, 22);
        panel.add(ID);
        ID.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
        lblLastName.setBounds(12, 68, 78, 16);
        panel.add(lblLastName);

        lastName = new JTextField();
        lastName.setBounds(79, 65, 171, 22);
        panel.add(lastName);
        lastName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
        lblFirstName.setBounds(262, 68, 78, 16);
        panel.add(lblFirstName);

        firstName = new JTextField();
        firstName.setBounds(332, 65, 171, 22);
        panel.add(firstName);
        firstName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblMi = new JLabel("mi");
        lblMi.setBounds(529, 68, 56, 16);
        panel.add(lblMi);

        mi = new JTextField();
        mi.setBounds(560, 65, 56, 22);
        panel.add(mi);
        mi.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblAdress = new JLabel("Address");
        lblAdress.setBounds(12, 116, 56, 16);
        panel.add(lblAdress);

        address = new JTextField();
        address.setBounds(79, 113, 424, 22);
        panel.add(address);
        address.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblCity = new JLabel("City");
        lblCity.setBounds(12, 158, 56, 16);
        panel.add(lblCity);

        city = new JTextField();
        city.setBounds(79, 155, 216, 22);
        panel.add(city);
        city.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblState = new JLabel("State");
        lblState.setBounds(332, 158, 56, 16);
        panel.add(lblState);

        state = new JTextField();
        state.setBounds(387, 155, 116, 22);
        panel.add(state);
        state.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblTelephone = new JLabel("Telephone");
        lblTelephone.setBounds(12, 204, 78, 16);
        panel.add(lblTelephone);

        tel = new JTextField();
        tel.setBounds(80, 201, 423, 22);
        panel.add(tel);
        tel.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("View");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(80, 289, 97, 25);
        panel.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Insert");
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(187, 289, 97, 25);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_1);
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                try {
                    DbMethods.insert();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Update");
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(291, 289, 97, 25);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_2);

        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("Clear");
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(400, 289, 97, 25);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_3);
    }
}
```

When I run the second class and try to insert a record into database I get the null pointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DbMethods.insert(DbMethods.java:45)
    at DbInterface$2.actionPerformed(DbInterface.java:162)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and I don't know why, if anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: If you've done even a little searching on solving a NullPointerException (NPE), you'll know that the most important bit of information that we need is the exception's associated stacktrace and some identification of the line that causes it, something that the stacktrace will tell you, and unfortunately neither of which you've posted here with your question. Please fix this so that we can help you.

Comment: I edited the question and added all the information about the error, I hope that would help.

Comment: If you start the program by calling the `main(....)` method in `DbInterface` the `statement` variable in `DbMethods` will be `null`, if you started it by calling `main(...)` in `DbMethods` all of the variables in  `DbInterface` will be `null`

Comment: What about using debugger?

Comment: @Titus: consider writing that as an answer.

Comment: As a side recommendation, you're grossly over-using the static modifier. Why is this a problem? For one, it often leads to creation of code that has numerous and difficult to control connections, the so-called "highly coupled" code problem since static variables are *global*. New instances of classes filled with static fields cannot have their own "*state*", their own variables with unique values. Also static fields and methods are difficult to test and debug.

Comment: This suggests that you may be putting the "cart before the horse", that is trying to learn a complex corner of Java, here Swing GUI programming ***combined*** with database programming, before learning the basics of Java and how to do object oriented programming with Java. Start at the beginning and learn the fundamentals first if you want to avoid a host of frustrations.

Comment: I just invoked the main method of DbMethods in DbInterface's main method. It worked! thanks for the help.

Comment: Shaking my head. Seriously no -- don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you start the program by calling the `main(....)` method in `DbInterface` the statement variable in `DbMethods` will be `null`, if you started it by calling `main(...)` in `DbMethods` all of the variables in `DbInterface` will be `null`.

Also, don't execute database operation on the EDT.

You can modify the `DbMethods` class to something like this:

```
public class DbMethods {
    public void insert(String f1,String f2 ....){
       if(f1.isEmpty()){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DbInterface.contentPane, "The ID cannot be null!", "Invalid info", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }else{
             Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook","root","");
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO personnel(ID, LastName, FirstName, mi, Address, City, State, Telephone) VALUES('"+f1+"','"+f2+"'"+....+")");
        }
     }

}
```

And in the `DbInterface` class you can call the `insert(...)` method like this:

```
 btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                     new DbMethods().insert(id.getText(), lastName.getText(),....);   
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

You should consider using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` and create only a single connection to the database.